# Autoload y Namespaces en PHP

Tags: php

no consigo vincular el autoload de php con los namespaces de cada clase, tengo el directorio siguiente

```
App
   Controller
      usuarioController.php
public
   index.php
.htaccess
```

Y en cada archivo tengo lo siguiente

#### .htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/index.php?route=$1 [QSA]
```

#### App/Controller/usuarioController.php

```
<?php 
    class usuarioController {
        function saludar() {
            echo "hola";
        }
    }
```

#### public/index.php

```
<?php

    define("PROJECTPATH", dirname(__DIR__));

    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        $filename = PROJECTPATH . '/App/Controller/' . $class . '.php';
        include_once $filename; 
    });

    $var = new usuarioController();
    echo $var->saludar();
```

El codigo anterior funciona perfectamente, es decir, esta funcionando el autoload pero cuando agrego los namespace me da error 500, y en verdad no entiendo por que.

Estos serian los codigos que me estan generando el error, estan en negrita. ayuda

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Controller\Usuario;
    class usuarioController {
        function saludar() {
            echo "hola";
        }
    }
```

y en el index llamo al namespace de la siguiente forma

```
<?php

    define("PROJECTPATH", dirname(__DIR__));

    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        $filename = PROJECTPATH . '/App/Controller/' . $class . '.php';
        include_once $filename; 
    });

    use App\Controller\Usuario;
    $var = new usuarioController();
    echo $var->saludar();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corregiré toda mi respuesta entre otras cosas, porque confundí el estamento `namespace` con `use` «Cuestión de copy-paste»

Retomemos tu ejemplo:

```
define("PROJECTPATH", dirname(__DIR__));

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $filename = PROJECTPATH . '/App/Controller/' . $class . '.php';
    include_once $filename; 
});

use App\Controller\Usuario;
$var = new usuarioController();
echo $var->saludar();
```

Cuando usas la linea

```
use App\Controller\Usuario;
```

> Es como si le dijeras al interprete *"importa **{ALGO}** que se llama `App\Controller\Usuario` y desearía en adelante darle un alias corto como `Usuario`"*
>
> ```
>  //Este es el equivalente
>  use App\Controller\Usuario as Usuario;
> ```
>
> http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php

Teniendo en cuenta como defines la clase

```
namespace App\Controller\Usuario;

class usuarioController {
    function saludar() {
        echo "hola";
    }
}
```

Lo correcto es que importes de esta manera

```
use App\Controller\Usuario\usuarioController;
```

Lo anterior resuelve el problema en cuanto a como importas, el detalle es que estabas usando mal el estamento `use`. Ahora Ya resuelto esto entremos a otro detalle **La ruta del archivo que contiene la definición de la clase**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $filename = PROJECTPATH . '/App/Controller/' . $class . '.php';
    include_once $filename; 
});
$var = new App\Controller\Usuario\usuarioController();
```

Al ejecutar esta linea

```
$var = new App\Controller\Usuario\usuarioController();
```

El interprete intentará buscar la definición de la clase que quieres instanciar y al no encontrarla disparara la cola de __autoload proporcionada por spl, en términos mas simples mas o menos «Ejecutar la función que registraste con el `spl_autoload_register` pasando-le por parámetro el nombre completo de la clase que deseas instanciar osea 'App\Controller\Usuario\usuarioController'»

```
function($class) {
   $filename = PROJECTPATH . '/App/Controller/' . $class . '.php';
   include_once $filename; 
}
// Así $class = 'App\Controller\Usuario\usuarioController'
// Por tanto $filename = PROJECTPATH . '/App/Controller/App\Controller\Usuario\usuarioController.php'
```

Posiblemente ya te habrás dado cuenta del fallo, en windows cuyo delimitador por defecto de directorios es '\' esto traduciría a una estructura así:

```
App
+-Controller
  +-App
    +-Controller
      +-Usuario
        +-usuarioController.php
```

Muy diferente a lo que tienes ¿Verdad?

---

### Posible solución

Creo que lo que intentas es esto

> Archivo: App/Controller/usuarioController.php

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Controller;

    class usuarioController {
        function saludar() {
            echo "hola";
        }
    }
```

> Archivo a ejecutar

```
<?php

    define("PROJECTPATH", dirname(__DIR__));

    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        $filename = PROJECTPATH . "/$class.php";
        include_once $filename; 
    });

    use App\Controller\usuarioController as Usuario;
    $usuario = new Usuario();
    echo $usuario->saludar();
```

Ahora esto expuesto anteriormente solo funcionará en windons puesto que al buscar `PROJECTPATH . '/App\Controller\usuarioController.php'` este interpretará algo así `C:\...\App\Controller\usuarioController.php` mientras que en linux la situacion será un tanto diferente teniendo en cuenta que el separador de directorios es '/' entonces `.../App\Controller\usuarioController.php` no será interpretado como esperarías sino mas o menos algo así:

```
App
   Controller\usuarioController.php //La barra invertida puede contituir parte del nombre
```

Para corregir esto debes indicarle a PHP que remplace las barras '\' y '/' por el delimitador correspondiente, así:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
   $filename = PROJECTPATH . "/$class.php";
   $filename_real = str_replace(['/',"\\"],DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$filename);
   include_once $filename_real; 
});
```

Para ser mas didáctico lo he mostrado en una linea extra

```
$filename_real = str_replace(['/',"\\"],DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$filename);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero en verdad, no estoy muy familiarizado con esto aun asi que no me ayudo mucho, pero igualmente, gracias

Comment: Ok, dame unos minutos y te colaboro con una explicación mas precisa

Comment: He entrado en detalles en cuanto al fallo que tenias, y adicional agregue una posible solución, espero te sea de utilidad para comprender mejor esto.

Comment: Tengo una buena y mala noticia. La buena es que el codigo ha funcionado, el que me recomedaste sin embargo, tuvo un error pequeno que fue en esta parte `$filename = PROJECTPATH . $class . '.php';`, el correcto es `$filename = PROJECTPATH . "/" . $class . '.php';` este lo probe en windows, sin embargo, por alguna extrana razon este mismo codigo no me funciona en linux que es donde yo estaba trabajando y en verdad no entiendo porque, Eres un crack. Solo me queda averiguar que esta pasando en linux

Comment: Ya vi, todo es cuestion de versiones, que tonteria. En windows uso PHP 7 y en linux 5.6, pero tenia entendido que el uso de namespace esta disponible desde PHP 5

Comment: Anexe de igual forma un método que se usa para evitar el problema de los separadores de directorios en función del sistema operativo. Por cierto, si soluciono tu pregunta puntuala como respuesta para que contribuya a otras personas.

Comment: Hola gracias, ya lo hago sin embargo, me gustaria que corrigieras en tu respuesta lo que te mencione. Y ya lo solucione para linux tambien, de esta manera `$filename = PROJECTPATH . "/" . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';` ... gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Esta bien , no habia visto la ultima linea que anadiste, pues si asi fue como lo solucione :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66805/discussion-between-nekoos-and-anthony-medina).